# Adicionar Informações em um arquivo em uma linha especifica

Tags: php, arquivo, file-put-contents

Estou usando o `file_put_contents` para criar um arquivo, mas em uma determinada parte do meu processo eu preciso adicionar coisas nesse arquivo mas apenas a partir da linha 2, eu procurei na documentação do PHP de `file_put_contents` e não achei nada, alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma é ler o arquivo e colocá-lo num `array`, por índice você indica a linha e altera o valor.

```
$linhas = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents("arquivo1.txt"));
$numeroLinha = 2;

$linhas[$numeroLinha] = "foo bar";

file_put_contents("foo.txt" , implode(PHP_EOL, $linhas));
```

Se preferir ler linha por linha:

```
function AdicionarLinha($arquivo, $numeroLinha, $conteudo){
    $arquivoTemporario = "$arquivo.bak";
    $linhaAtual = 0;

    $fpRead  = fopen($arquivo, 'r');
    $fpWrite = fopen($arquivoTemporario, 'w');

    try{
        if ($fpRead) {
            while (($linha = fgets($fpRead)) !== false) {
                if ($linhaAtual == $numeroLinha){
                    $linha .= $conteudo . PHP_EOL; // Para substituir, use "="
                }

                fwrite($fpWrite, $linha);
                $linhaAtual += 1;       
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $err) {
        echo $err->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    }
    finally {
        fclose($fpRead);
        fclose($fpWrite);

        unlink($arquivo); // Para deletar o arquivo original
        rename($arquivoTemporario, $arquivo); // Para renomear o arquivo
    }
}
```

Para usar, faça assim:

```
AdicionarLinha("arquivo1.txt", 2, "foo bar"); // Adiciona "foo bar" a partir da linha 2
```

Comment: Existe outra alternativa? Meu arquivo pode ter 20.000+ linhas, se eu transformar tudo isso em array vai dar exaust memory e eu não posso alterar o memory_limit do php.ini

Comment: @IvanMoreira Editei a resposta e coloquei outra, veja se é isso.

Comment: Eu vi, mas não quero substituir as linha existentes, quero adicionar novas linhas.

Comment: @IvanMoreira Já atualizei, é só usar `.=` no ao invés de `=`, se preferir verificar se arquivo existe antes, use a função [`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-exists.php).

Comment: Entendi como funciona, valeu!

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado @stderr

Answer (score 0):

Poderia usar comandos de shell. No exemplo abaixo, usamos o `sed`.

```
$file = escapeshellarg('tmp.txt');
shell_exec('sed /5/ a foo '.$file);
/*
Adiciona "foo" na quinta linha do arquivo

A letra "a" concatena (append)
Caso queira inserir numa nova linha, use letra "i" (insert)
*/
```

O teste foi feito num arquivo de 2mb, 661980 linhas (660 mil linhas).

Tempo de execução: 0.014498949050903 (microsegundos)

Pico de memória: 435040 bytes

Memória final: 398224 butes

Para confirmar a integridade da performance, o mesmo arquivo foi aumentado em 8 vezes, 16mb.

O tempo de execução foi o mesmo.

```
Windows 10 Pro 64bit
PHP 7.0.5
Apache 2.4.20
```

Para usar o aplicativo `sed` sob ambiente Windows: https://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/?source=typ_redirect