# Dúvida sobre comando PHP para escrever dentro de outro arquivo .php

Tags: php, arquivo, fopen

Estou encontrando um problema no seguinte código:

```
<?php

$id = $_POST['id'];
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$imagem = $_POST['imagem'];
$coment = $_POST['coment'];

$finalcoment = '<div id="triplox"><a name="index-' . $id . '"></a><br><div id="idnoticias"><center><a href="HTML/Noticias/index-' . $id . '.php"><u>' . $titulo . '</u></a></center></div><br><br><center><img width="90%" height="90%" src="Imagens/' . $imagem . '.jpg"></center><p>' . $coment . '</p><br><center>Postado : ' . date('d/m/y') . '</center><br><br></div>' ;

// abre o arquivo colocando o ponteiro de escrita no final
$arquivo = fopen('../../../HTML/noticias.php','a+');
if ($arquivo) {
    // move o ponteiro para o inicio do arquivo
    rewind($arquivo);
    if (!fwrite($arquivo, $finalcoment)) die('Não foi possível atualizar o arquivo.');
    echo 'Arquivo atualizado com sucesso';
    fclose($arquivo);
}

?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; ../noticias.php">
```

Em teoria ele deveria pegar os valores da *strings*, montar ele dentro do código para escrever no começo da outro arquivo `.php`. Ele esta escrevendo o código tudo certinho mas não no começo da pagina, ele esta escrevendo em continuação ao ultimo código digitado. Ai vem a grande pergunta, o que eu fiz de errado no código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação da função [`rewind`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rewind.php):

> Se você abriu arquivo no modo *append* (`a` ou `a+`), qualquer
>   informação que você escrever para o arquivo será sempre adicionada,
>   desconsiderando a posição no arquivo.

Se o arquivo que você quer manipular não for muito pesado, use as funções [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) para ler o conteúdo e [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-put-contents.php) para escrever:

```
$finalcoment  = "<div id=.... \n";
$finalcoment .= file_get_contents('noticias.php');

file_put_contents('noticias.php', $finalcoment);
```

Se preferir usar as funções `fopen`, `fwrite`, [**nessa resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/149749/6454) tem uma implementação.

Comment: Funcionou certinho  vlw

Answer (score 1):

Funcionou bem esse método do `file_get_contents` e `file_put_contents` só tive que ajeitar o `$finalcoment` para encaixar certo na pagina dando espaço na linha de cima e de baixo, ai ele deixa uma linha sempre sobrando para o próximo código que vai entra neste arquivo. Ficou assim:

```
<?php

$id = $_POST['id'];
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$imagem = $_POST['imagem'];
$coment = $_POST['coment'];

$finalcoment = '
<div id="triplox"><a name="index-' . $id . '"></a><br><div id="idnoticias"><center><a href="HTML/Noticias/index-' . $id . '.php"><u>' . $titulo . '</u></a></center></div><br><br><center><img width="90%" height="90%" src="Imagens/' . $imagem . '.jpg"></center><p>' . $coment . '</p><br><center>Postado : ' . date('d/m/y') . '</center><br><br></div>
' ;

$finalcoment .= file_get_contents('noticias.php');

file_put_contents('noticias.php', $finalcoment);

echo "Noticia adicionada com sucesso!";
?>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; noticias.php">
```

no caso eu dei um <kbd>ENTER</kbd> no começo e no final do código, dentro das aspas simples, ai ele é adicionado ao código junto.